# My second function stub seems to infinite loop?

Tags: c, function, loops, stub, infinite

I have two relatively the same stub functions and yet when i call the second stub it seems to infinite loop and i am not sure why. The function that i am calling in this code that infinite loops is convert_weight();. I have my doubts as to if it is a main program problem, since it gets called in and prints out the first few printfs without problem but when user input from scanf is used, it goes into infinite loop. Any help would be useful, please and thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void convert_lengths(int users_choice);
void convert_weight(int users_choice);
void length_to_metric(void);
void length_to_us(void);
void weight_to_metric(void);
void weight_to_us(void);

int main()
{
    int users_choice;
    do
    {
        printf("Do you want to convert length or weights?\n");
        printf("1 for length\n");
        printf("2 for weights\n");
        printf("0 to end program\n");
        scanf("%d", &users_choice);
        if(users_choice == 1)
        {
            convert_lengths(users_choice);
        }
        if(users_choice == 2)
        {
            convert_weight(users_choice);
        }
    }while(users_choice != 0);
    return 0;
}
void convert_lengths(int a)
{
    int b;
    do
    {
        if(a == 1)
        {
            printf("You have chosen to convert lengths\n");
            printf("What units do you want to convert?\n");
            printf("- 1 to convert feet/inches to meters/centimeters\n");
            printf("- 2 to convert from meters/centimeters to feet/inches\n");
            printf("- 0 to go back to other options\n");
            scanf("%d", &b);
            if(b == 1)
            {
                printf("You have chosen to convert feet/inches to meters/centinmeters\n\n");
                length_to_metric();
            }
            if(b == 2)
            {
                printf("You have chosen to convert meters/centimeters to feet/inches\n\n");
                length_to_us();
            }
        }
    }while(b != 0);
}
void convert_weight(int a)
{
    int b;
    do
    {

        if(a == 2)
        {
           printf("You have chosen to convert weights\n");
           printf("What units of weight do you want to convert?\n");
           printf("- 1 for pounds/ounces to kilograms/grams\n");
           printf("- 2 for kilograms/gram to pounds/ounces\n");
           printf("- 0 to go back to other options\n");
           scanf("%b", &b);
           if(b == 1)
           {
               printf("You have chosen to convert pounds/ounces to kilograms/gram\n\n");
               weight_to_metric();

           }
           if(b == 2)
           {
               printf("You have chosen to convert kilograms/gram to pounds/ounces\n\n");
               weight_to_us();
           }
        }

    }while(b != 0);
}
void length_to_metric(void)
{
    return;
}
void length_to_us(void)
{
    return;
}
void weight_to_metric(void)
{
    return;
}
void weight_to_us(void)
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: think about what happens when `a != 2` in convert_weight - b is not guaranteed to be 0

Comment: Surely `length_to_us` should be `length_to_imperial`. Also do not need those returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used the wrong format specifier for `scanf` in the `convert_weight` function:

```
scanf("%b", &b);
        ^
```

It is supposed to be `%d`, which reads an integer.

Comment: ah yes, thanks! I seem to get tunnel vision when I look at my functions, it always turns out to be problems with scanf generally.

Comment: You should take those `if(a==2)` tests out of your loops.  If you were to call the functions and supply the wrong parameter, you would get an infinite loop.  The parameter in this case seems completely pointless.

Comment: But, wouldn't these work to have the loop repeat until i had put in proper parameters? through the do-while loop i mean

Comment: You never modify `a` in those functions.  If `a` has the wrong value, the loops will be infinite because you will never enter the code block that reads a value for `b` (ignoring for a second that it's also undefined behaviour because `b` is uninitialised).

Comment: OH thanks again, lol I see since through user input i am calling functions anyways, it wouldn't matter if it had that if statement, really clears things up.